# Masking numpy arrays to select specific rows, based on another boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

Suppose that I have an array like this:

```
my_arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

or a 2D array like:

```
my_arr = np.array([[1, 1, 11], [2, 1, 0], [3, 3, -1], ..., [10, 9, 0]])
```

And I define an array like

mask_arr = ([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])

What I want to do from the mask array is to obtain a new array which is consisted of rows, wherein the mask_arr of their index, the element is equal to "1".

For example, the result of the first array would be like:

```
[1, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 8, , 10]
```

I tried

```
my_arr[my_mask]
```

But it didn't work. Is there any solution without wanting to write a for loop to do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `my_arr[my_mask.astype(bool)]`.

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much. Would you please make it as a reply so I can check the green tick? (for accepting it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `mask_arr` looks like integer type, and when you slice with an integer array, the array is treated as indexes. So

```
my_arr[[0,1,1]]
```

would give you `[row0,row1,row1]`. As you mentioned, you want to treat `mask_arr` as boolean, then you can convert it to boolean:

```
my_arr[mask_arr.astype('bool')]
```

will extract the rows corresponding to the `1` in `mask_arr`.